# How to add custom javscript feature in a UI Form Builder?

Tags: javascript, security, vuejs2, formbuilder, custom-code

Working on a Drag & Drop Form builder built in Vue. It will have the possibility to add custom javascript code that will run in the resulting Form.

Which is the best way to handle this?
Which is the best way to save the js code? Plain text in a database or is there a service (paid or open source) that sanitizes and saves/retrieves the code?
How to run the javascript code in the form? Execute function? How do I protect myself from security issues?